# Email address encoded within an email address. Is it possible?

Tags: email, mail-server, email-formats

I am looking into some edge cases of email address formatting, and also how such cases are handled by email servers.

In particular, according to RFC5322 (section 3.4.1), an address like this is valid:

> "test@test.com"@domain.com

Notice the double quotes surrounding the local part.

If such an address is valid, can it be handled by email servers?

If not by default, does anyone know if any open source email servers can be configured to handle such cases?

Thanks!

Comment: As an example, I am using Google Apps for one of my domains. Sending an email to "xyz"@mydomain.com works (i.e. the email is delivered to my default catch-all address), but sending to "xyz@adomain.com"@mydomain.com fails with a failed delivery notification from Google.

Answer (score -1):

Seeing as emails were originally a user account (and still sort of are) on a Web Server, they are valid. Usernames can have quotes.

It's handled perfectly fine by my web host, but most free email services don't allow quotes for this exact reason.

Comment: This is confused, if not factually incorrect, and fails to answer the question which MTAs can handle such addresses. -1